# Decreasing value in C# or VB.NET enum

Tags: c#, vb.net, enums

More for interest than actual need...
is it possible to have an automatically decreasing enum in C# or VB.NET?

```
public enum testEnum
{
    this = -1,
    that,
    other,
}
```

So that that = -2 and other = -3.

I'm pretty sure the only way to do it is to specifically assign "that" and "other", but I wondered if there was an automatic way of doing it.

**Edit**

To be clear, I'm simply talking about the automatic assignment of the value, not the actual value of the enum decreasing.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this. There also isn't really a good reason for wanting to do this. Hopefully if you were to ever find yourself in the situation that you wanted this strange behavior you could instead redesign the part of the system "requiring" it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You must declare the values if you wish to do so, or reverse the declaration:

```
public enum testEnum
{
    other = -3,
    that,
    @this
}
```

Comment: It's the obvious ones that are never obvious!  Thank you Oded

Comment: Technically, this is increasing not decreasing as the user specified, though I imagine it fits his need as he likely wants an `enum` of negative values. The downside with this is that you must maintain and manually count how many items are in your list.

Comment: @freefaller - Well, I do think it is not obvious that `that` is `-2` in my example.

Comment: Two good points, @Thomas and Oded.  I like it from a technical point of view, but agree that it is not obvious or easy to maintain.  As I said, it's more for interest than actual practical use

Comment: @Oded - Can I ask: what is the @ sign signifying on the "@this" enum item?

Comment: @freefaller - Since `this` is a reserved keyword in C#, it can't be used as an identifier. You can use `@` in front of such a keyword in order to turn it into a valid identifier name. See on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

Comment: @Oded - Doh, of course! I typed the answer direct into stackoverflow so didn't think of that.  As I try to never use reserved words for variables, I'd forgotten about that syntax... my stupid choice of an example!  Thanks